# Jenkins - Run same job on DIFFERENT machine concurrently

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

Here is the scenario for the problem. I have one job which plays with machine host file.
I want to run that job with flag(to change host) as 0 and 1 concurrently.

Got to know about Jenkins plugin for concurrent run but it may happen that both job instances run on same slave and creating problem with host file(different flags to change/unchange the file)

I am looking for something by which i can run both instances, BUT ON DIFFERENT SLAVES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**throttle concurrent builds plugin** - in configuration of plugin set Maximum Concurrent Builds Per Node = 1

Comment: Hey jussuper, the plugin is great but i can see that if other nodes are not available, it starts the concurrent job on the same machine. I have set Maximum Total Concurrent Builds as 3 and Maximum Concurrent Builds Per Node as 1

Comment: did you checked "Execute concurrent job if necessary" for this job? you  can also use Node and Label parameter plugin to select (as a parameter) the node where a job should be executed.

Comment: Sorry for getting soo late here. :)

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, you can use the "[Throttle Concurrent Builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin)". It's compatible with Jenkins 2.0 as well.

To Configure this plugin, just download and install this plugin. Once done, go to job configuration and you will see "Throttle Concurrent Builds" in General section. Check that option and you will be asked for further configuration.

Please find below the screenshot for the same.

[image]

if you have multiple projects you can uncheck the "throttle this project alone"

and to utilize to the fullest, you can keep the "maximum total concurrent builds" to a number of slaves that you have. for example. let's say you have 8 nodes so you can configure it to run 8 concurrent instances of this build.

and for "maximum concurrent builds per node" you can keep it as 1 if you want only one node to build one instance.